# why i get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'place_forget'

Tags: python

im trying to make a gui and getting the error on the line for button command function.
this is my function:

```
dmButtonVariable = IntVar()
dmButtonVariable.set(True)
def goDm():
    if dmButtonVariable== True:
        dmframe.place(x=0,y=0)
    else:
        dmframe.place_forget()
dm_icon = PhotoImage(file="send.png")
dm_icon_button=Button(frame2, image = dm_icon, command=goDm)
dm_icon_button.place(x=365, y=5)
```

if i change dm_icon_button line to this:

```
dm_icon_button=Button(frame2, image = dm_icon, command=goDm, variable=dmButtonVariable)
```

then i get _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-variable" error.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the dmframe variable. Try printing it out and see what it says. You can also print(help(dmframe)) to see if it has the method .place_forget() in it.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre]. What is `dmframe`?

Comment: firstly, thanks for answering..
i replace the function to this:

def goDm():
    if dmButtonVariable== True:
        dmframe=Frame(window, width=400, height=600, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
        dmframe.place(x=0,y=0)
    else:
        dmframe=Frame(window, width=400, height=600, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)
        dmframe.place(x=0,y=0)
        dmframe.place_forget(dmframe)

now, im getting TypeError: place_forget() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given error when i click the dm_icon_button

Comment: im trying make a gui. my goal is switching the main window to dmframe when i click the dm_icon_button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem. i dont need intvar or something else if im trying to do button events.
i was trying to switching through frames with "if loop" in button command def. i dont need "if loops". it already means "if" via button command.
here's my new code:

```
def goSearchBarButton():
    searchbarFrame = Frame(messageWindow,width =400, height=600, 
                           relieftkinter.FLAT)
    searchbarFrame.place(x=0,y=0)
```